# How can I get the value of the first observable in a chain of observables relationship

Tags: angular, rxjs

I work with an application where I use the Angular Model Pattern.

What am I trying to achieve is this: after adding an article of a certain type, I want two things to happen:

1. to load again the newspaper(this refreshes the model: model.Newspaper);
2. after the newspaper is loaded, I want to reload the list of articles of that certain type (this refreshes the model: model.ArticlesOfSomeType);

For whatever reason, I don't have a list property of Articles on Newspaper.

I have two Observables that I am working with:

```
artikelAdded$: Observable<{ newspaperId: number, artikelType: string}>;
```

The newspaperService.load method returns an Observable<"Newspaper">. Let's say for example:

```
load(newspaperId):Observable<Newspaper> { 
   // observable is created from a Promise of getting the Newspaper
   // when the Promise is resolved, here the model.Newspaper is set
}
```

And also, the "reloadArticlesOfType" will set the other part of the model:

```
reloadArticlesOfType(newspaperId, type) = {
     model.ArticlesOfSomeType = GetArticles(newspaperId, type);
}
```

What I am trying to do , is something like this:

```
this.actionCompletedService.artikelAdded$
    .pipe(
       map(artikelAdded => this.newspaperService.load(artikelAdded.NewspaperId)),
       switchMap(loadNewspaper$ => loadNewspaper$)
    )
    .subscribe(newspaper => this.newspaperService
                           .reloadArticlesOfType(newspaper.Id, artikelAdded.artikelType));
```

Of course this doesn't work because I don't have **artikelAdded.artikelType** in my scope, when I need it. I don't know how to chain my Observables to get what I want. I am relatively new working with Angular and Observables so any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can probably simplify a bit the code by removing `switchMap(loadNewspaper$ => loadNewspaper$)` and using directly `concatMap` instead of `map` as the first operator.

Then, getting to the core of your question, you can pipe a `map` operator into the result of `this.newspaperService.load(artikelAdded.NewspaperId)` to return both `artikelAdded` and `newspaper`.

The code would look something like this

```
this.actionCompletedService.artikelAdded$
    .pipe(
       concatMap(artikelAdded => this.newspaperService.load(artikelAdded.NewspaperId)).pipe(map(newspaper => ({newspaper, artikelAdded})))
    )
    .subscribe(newspaperAndArticle => this.newspaperService
                           .reloadArticlesOfType(newspaperAndArticle.newspaper.Id, newspaperAndArticle.artikelAdded.artikelType));
```

This should work since you pass to `subscribe` an object which contains both `newspaper` and `article`.